# Custom file property not displayed by windows explorer

Tags: c#, file, properties

I found this: http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2008/06/how-to-set-custom-attributes-dyfile.html
and any details I setup are not display in windows explorer. I tried both SummaryProperties and CustomProperties for different file types, like: txt, doc, mp3, pdf.
Is there any way that these properties can be displayed or use in search terms?

---

<sup>The OP's URL has apparently gone stale, but (http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2008/06/how-to-set-custom-attributes-file.html) works nicely.</sup>

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".