# Windows property handler: Is there no easier way than PerfectSteaks

Tags: c#, c++, windows-7, explorer

We haves custom binary files with cryptic names; the patient name in the file can be easily read with c++, c# or python. We would like to display the patient name in the Explorer mouseover, and as a custom property in the detail view.

I found a similar example in the sample `RecipePropertyHandler` of the SDK; understanding the code to modify it is not easy, though.

Is there no simpler toolkit without the overhead? It is very easy to write a simple dll that only returns the property and its name.

Added: this is an interesting tool, but currently does not allow for defining custom properties: http://filemeta.codeplex.com/

Comment: Check out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623832/custom-file-property-not-displayed-by-windows-explorer). As I recall what's involved down at the API level is (1) extra NTFS file streams, which is problematic when a file is copied over network or to different file system, and (2) the old OLE filesystem-in-a-file thing. Sorry I don't have time to investigate further. It's *possible* that on Vista and later you may use the generalized property scheme. I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, that was the first link I found (note that the link in the comment is the only one that works). However, in other messages I found that this is not going to be supported in future. Note that the message is from year 2008.